# Drawing Multiple Models with glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a struct to store vertex data for 2 distinct models one is a cube the other a pyramid.

```
struct Model{
    GLuint vboID;
    GLfloat* vbo;
    GLuint vaoID;
    GLfloat* vao; 
    GLuint vertexStart;
    GLuint vertexCount;
};
```

I create the vbos and generate their buffers like this:

```
Model cubeModel;
Model pyramidModel;

cubeModel.vbo = cubeVerts; //A GLfloat array I created earlier in code earlier. 
cubeModel.vertexCount= sizeof(cubeVerts);//size of the GLfloat array in bytes

pyramidModel.vbo = pyVerts; 
pyramidModel.vertexCount= sizeof(pyVerts);

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeModel.vboID); //Generate a buffer for the vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeModel.vboID); //Bind the vertex buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeModel.vertexCount, cubeModel.vbo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And then to draw I use:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, cubeModel.vertexCount);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Which works, and I successfully draw the cube, But i've been trying multiple ways to draw the pyramid as well.

What do I need to do to render both on screen at the same time?

EDIT: Here's what i've tried specifically, duplicating the glBufferData() call and passing in the pyramid data then making glDrawArays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,cubeModel.drawcount+pyramidModel.drawCount) figuring the vertex data would stack and glDrawArrays would go through all the geometry passed in one go.

I've also tried making 2 sets of instructions from glGenBuffers() to glDisableClientState() but instead using all of pyramid model's data. This was interesting because my glDrawArrays was:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, cubeModel.drawCount);
glTranslatef(4.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, pyramidModel.drawCount);
```

and it ended up drawing a really messed up pyramid 2 times, leading me to believe that when I cal glBufferData() twice the second time Overwrites the data previously passed.

EDIT 2:After Reading Andon's comment I edited some of my code to clarify things, drawCount is now vertexCount, and m_vertexBuffer is now correctly referencing the handle I stored in cubeModel, cubeModel.vboID, instead of using an old class variable I was using to store the handle.

Comment: You have the wrong idea about VBOs here... When I see a class/struct with a field named `vbo` the first thing that comes to my mind is: "this must be an OpenGL name (handle) to a VBO". You, on the other hand, are using this field to store the actual data that you will fill the VBO with. Instead of doing it the way you have it now, try making vbo a `GLuint` and doing something like: `glGenBuffers (1, &cubeModel.vbo)`. You can store your vertex data wherever you want, because after you feed it to a VBO you do not need it anymore. Also use `vertexCount` instead of `drawCount` for clarity.

Comment: I knew I would have a facepalm moment as soon as someone said something. I do have that stored in the struct as well. GLuint vboID in the Model struct. so in this case cubeModel.vboID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not want to muddy up the comments section, because there are a lot of things wrong with your code. But I also do not have time to go through all of them right now, so this is a sort of temporary answer.

`glBufferData (...)` does not technically overwrite previously passed data, it does something far worse. Every time you call `glBufferData (...)` it creates a new data store of the size you pass and (optionally) fills it with the data you supply (if you pass something non-NULL). Think of it more like calling `free (...)` and then `malloc (...)` or `delete [] ...` and `new Type [...]`.

`glBufferSubData (...)` is the preferred technique for appending vertices to a vertex buffer. Unfortunately it does not resize the data store. Sometimes it is handy to over-allocate your VBO and defer supplying it data until later on (using `glBufferSubData`).

If you use one VBO to store both of your models, you need to know the starting vertex and the vertex count for each model as it relates to your VBO's data. Right now all you know is the number of vertices (and you have it named strangely `drawCount` instead of `vertexCount`). To most people, `drawCount` indicates the number of times you want to draw something, rather than the number of vertices or elements it contains.

The size field of a call to `glBufferData (...)` is supposed to be the size in bytes of your vertex data. Right now you're passing the number of vertices. More than likely you meant to use `sizeof (YourVertexDataStructure)` for the size of an individual vertex (`sizeof (float [3])` in this case), and something like `sizeof (cubeVerts)` / `sizeof (YourVertexDataStructure)` to calculate the number of vertices actually stored in this array. Then the size you pass to `glBufferData (...)` would be: _size * count_

Comment: I made some changes to the original post for clarification, drawCount to vertexCount and I also placed the rest of my Model struct up there and referenced the handle located in the struct. Good to know about glBufferData(...) I am extremely new to OpenGL so I apologize for my awful code writing.

Comment: @JayPC: No problem, I usually hate giving people answers like "go read suchandsuch tutorial," but in this case I think it might be best if you had a look at an OpenGL tutorial that covers VBO creation. I would suggest: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html, it was written by one of the regulars on here and is part of a much larger series of tutorials on **Modern** OpenGL, if you start with that instead of random bits and pieces on the Internet you'll be up and working with shaders in a fraction of the time you would elsewhere.

Comment: I know The feeling, Ive actually read that one already and I am in the process of converting an direct mode project into modern code. Also **sizeof(cubeVerts) = 432** so its already in bytes(The model has 108 elements of size GLfloat)so cubeModel.vertexCount is the amount in bytes already. I use: **sizeof(cubeVerts)/sizeof(GLfloat)** to find how many elements. I knew that was the param was in bytes cause I looked up the method here->[link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml), And actually I have worked with shader's before, but in LWJGL/Java and in Direct mode

Comment: @JayPC: Okay, but you're using the size in bytes when you call `glDrawArrays (...)`, which wants the number of vertices and not the total bytes. That's why it is useful to distinguish between the two. It is usually more useful to store the vertex count and do a little bit of extra work to compute the size in bytes when needed. Your current code will definitely work (in the sense that it will draw at least ALL of your vertices), since the size in bytes is always larger than the number of vertices, but for every vertex beyond the end of the array you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Which would explain the rays running off in random directions. Makes sense. I missed that `glDrawArrays()` used the element count not the size in bytes. Now that thats taken care of, do I **have** to combine the 2 arrays together and pass them all at once with `glBufferData()` or is there a way to render them both separate?

Comment: @JayPC: No, you do not have to combine the arrays. You can use a VBO for each model. Then you would change the bound VBO and vertex pointers and draw. VAOs make this a lot easier, you can setup a VAO that binds the VBO(s) for your model and has all of the vertex pointers setup correctly, then you just change the bound VAO whenever you want to draw a different model.